# How to refer to an unidentified item inside an identified container in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<div id="myDiv">
   <ul>
     <li> Thing 1
     <li> Thing 2
   </ul>
</div>
```

I want to be able to add one new item to the list, which is unidentified.

If I do:

```
var x = $('#myDiv').has('ul')
```

I am actually referring to the correct div, but I want to refer to the ul itself so I can do an .append().

What is the correct way of doing this?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just select the element directly and append to it: `$('#myDiv ul').append('<li>New item...</li>');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can point to `ul` like this

```
$('#myDiv ul')
```

```js
$('#myDiv ul').append('<li>Item to append</li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
   <ul>
     <li> Thing 1
     <li> Thing 2
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can refer `<ul>` directly:-

```
$('ul').append('<li>Item 3 appended</li>');
```

Working snippet:-

```js
$('ul').append('<li>Item 3 appended</li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
   <ul>
     <li> Thing 1
     <li> Thing 2
   </ul>
</div>
```

***Note:-*** It will add `<li>` to all `<ul>'s` if multiple are present.

So if you want to append to specific `<ul>` take a reference to its parent

```
$('#myDiv ul').append('<li>Item 3 appended</li>');
```

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$('#myDiv ul').append('<li>Item 3 appended</li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
   <ul>
     <li> Thing 1
     <li> Thing 2
   </ul>
</div>
```